# modulo operator rendering poorly

Tags: support, mathjax

The `\mod` operator is padded with too much space: $a \mod b$. Am I missing something in the TeX, or is something configured wrong?

I've tried with Firefox and Safari on OS X.

Comment: It's the correct behavior. If you want a "mod" with less space use `\bmod` (as in "binary mod"): $a \bmod b$. `\mod` is more keeping with the spirit of `\pmod`: $a \pmod{b}$.

Comment: TeX.SE: [typesetting modulus operator, as in remainder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42866/typesetting-modulus-operator-as-in-remainder) BTW there is also `\pmod` if you want to get something like $x^2\equiv-1 \pmod n$.

Comment: Thanks. I chose `\pmod`. It looks like `\mod` is really useless and broken, but this is the wrong forum to complain about that :P .

Comment: Just to make sure that you know: `\bmod` is designed to look good if you want the remainder. Like $(7\bmod 5)=2$. OTOH `\pmod`is designed to look good, if you want a congruence. Like $5\equiv 7\pmod2$ or $14\equiv11\pmod3$. With `\bmod` the 'value' of the calculation is an integer. The 'value' of a congruence OTOH is boolean, because it is semantically a comparison operation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh, thanks, I guess my usage was wrong, then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What `\mod` is for:

$$ 5 \equiv 8 \mod 3$$

What `\bmod` is for:

$$ 5 \bmod 3 = 2 $$

And for completeness, `\pmod`:

$$ -1 \equiv 8 \pmod 3$$

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround with `\mod` (being a little forgetful and more than a little obstinate), I sometimes use the thin negative space modifier `\!` to remove the excess whitespace.  Here are the results without the modifier, followed by using it once and then twice:

$$ 5 \equiv 8 \mod 3 $$

$$ 5 \equiv 8 \! \mod 3 $$

$$ 5 \equiv 8 \!\! \mod 3 $$

I generally find the latter to be about what I want for inline "modulo" equations.

Comment: you can also use `\hspace{-2mm}`